# SSRS - Hide a row in group based on value

Tags: reporting-services

I have the table below in SSRS, i would like to hide a row contains the value "MT" (which in a group "Date").

[image: http://imgur.com/a/tcesO]

This is the result without expression on row visibility:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/MeBsk]

And this is the result with the expression on the Row visibility:

```
=IIF(Fields!Message_type.Value = "MT", False, True)
```

[image: http://imgur.com/a/f4xB6]

It deletes all the table because of the group i guess, i want to keep the column "Date" and hide only the row with "MT" value.

Could somebody tell me how can i do it please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use filter expression (Group Properties > Filter) in order to hide record with Message_type equal to "MT".

Comment: How can i do that please ?

Comment: Right click on row header near [Date] field > Row Group > Group properties > Filter

Comment: I set the expression and the result was an ERROR, should i fill the value too on the filter parameter ?

Comment: Expression = [Message_type]; Operator = <>; Valore = "MT"

Comment: It hides all the table ! it keeps only the header ...

Comment: Even if you remove your row visibility expression?

Comment: yes, expression already deleted.

Comment: @Smail  You are applying your filters and visibility settings to the wrong places.  Please add more screenshots to show exactly what you have tries and the results.  The advice you have already been given is correct and will work if done correctly, but without being able to see how you are actually applying it, we can't tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @tezzo i just sent you the screenshort :) on my reply below.